# Input bar on mobile: automatically push to top on select

Tags: javascript, mobile, input, autocomplete

In mobile the touch keyboard would occupied the lower half of the screen, hence in case the input/text area is not at the top, if you have some kind of typeahead suggestion, they may not be in the view when the user is typing. Is there a way to automatically "push" the input field to the top when the input field is active, so as to maximize the visible area below it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind an event on the `[focus][1]` event of your inputs and then scroll (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)) to where you want. With jquery, it would look about like that, not tested:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
  $('body').scrollTop($(this).position().top);
  });
```

I am not sure about the body selection, i guess it depends on how your pages is defined.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. As I tested, the focus part of the code work but not the scrollTop function. (I already included the jquery library.) Is there any other function to achieve the same effect?

Comment: See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLQnz/) for working example. I just don't know how to scroll your page, it depends on how the content is displayed. See edited answer.